# Mock BeanInfo class from Object using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, beaninfo

Suppose I have the following method structure:

```
protected static void sub(Object obj, String filler) {

    class cls = obj.getClass();
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(cls);

    // Other code...
}
```

How do I mock the BeanInfo class given this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this logic to separate method:

```
static BeanInfo beanInfo(Object obj) {
    Class cls = obj.getClass();
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(cls);
}
```

and then mock `beanInfo` method.

Comment: All you did was remove an argument. How do I go from mockClass to mockBeanInfo? Wait, I see your point...

Answer (score 0):

You should code with [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) in mind. Then you can pass the mock as a parameter in your test.

```
protected static void sub(BeanInfo beanInfo, String filler) {
    // code...
}
```